# Is it possible to share an xml file on the network?

Tags: android, xamarin

In my Android application, I want my app to make an xml file available for download for anyone else in the network with HTTP GET. For example if my Android device's ip address is `192.168.6.54`, other devices can download "http://192.168.6.54/file.xml". Is this possible?

I'm developing in Xamarin.Forms, but I don't think that's important. An answer concerning only Android would be great.

Comment: For that you would need to turn your Android into a Webserver. I worked on something similar using this library https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd, **HanoHttp**. Unfortunately this one does not exist for Xamarin projects

Comment: I suggest you use azure for file storing and sharing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/storage/azure-storage.  
It is not only simple and powerful, but also can be seamlessly connected to Xamarin. 
But if I you really want to use your android device for some reason, you can make your android device to be a web server using this https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-android-device-web-server/